# How to detect whether a submission on Reddit is a self post using PRAW?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

Is it possible to detect whether a user's submission on reddit is either a self-post or a link to an external URL? I want to exclude all self-posts but can seem to find anything in PRAW's documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the attributes listed in the json data of the following URL are available as attributes:

http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/.json?limit=1

The attribute you might be interested in specifically is `is_self`. In PRAW, you need only test `submission.is_self`.